# How to backup single datasets of mariadb using php only

Tags: php, backup, mariadb

I have a php clean up script performing several deletions of single entries

```
"delete from table0 where id=5";
"delete from table1 where customerId=5";

...
```

Before I delete, I want to backup and safely dump these data sets.

What is the best way to do so to be able to restore it later.
I was about loading assoc array, serialize it and dump it to a single file by using fopen...

any better hints?

Comment: I know, normally I would do that, but that would need the change many, many classes and php scripts to exclude datasets which "deleted_at is not null"

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump ... dbname tblname
```

will dump a single table in a format that can be fed to `mysql` for reloading.

Be careful to ask for (or avoid getting) `DROP`, `CREATE`, etc.

The output will be a text file, so you can inspect the dump to see if it does what you want.